# Запрос на выборку из нескольких таблиц SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eсть два поста `Post121` и `Post122`, которые относится к категории `Test1` подкатегории `Test12`

Есть таблица `wp_post`:

```
 ID | post_title | post_name |
157 | Post121    | post121   |
159 | Post122    | post122   |
```

Таблица `wp_term_relationships`:

```
object_id | term_taxonomy_id |
 1        | 1                |
 157      | 4                |
 159      | 4                |
```

Таблица `wp_term_taxonomy`:

```
 term_taxonomy_id | term_id |
 2                | 2       |
 3                | 3       | 
 4                | 4       |
 5                | 5       |
```

Таблица `wp_terms`:

```
 term_id | name   |
 2       | Test1  |
 3       | Test11 |
 4       | Test12 |
```

нужно сделать выборку чтобы получилось:

```
 PostTitle | CategoryTitle |
 Post121   | Test12        |
 Post122   | Test12        |
```

Comment: джойн джойн и еще раз джойн

Comment: можешь сделать?

Comment: дойшло SELECT `wp_posts`.`post_title`, `wp_terms`.`name`
                                 FROM  `wp_posts`
                                 INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships`
                                 ON `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id`
                                 INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy`
                                 ON `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` =  `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id`
                                 INNER JOIN `wp_terms`
                                 ON  `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_id` = `wp_terms`.`term_id`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT p.post_title AS PostTitle, t.name AS CategoryTitle
FROM wp_post AS p
JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
```

Как-то так. Возможно, закралась ошибка – проверьте на живой базе...